# How can I pass ApplicationContext into the function in a new Thread()?

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, android-asynctask, android-context

I need to get location information about GPS location every 30 seconds in an infinity loop and send in to a server via HTTP-request. Endless cycle if GPS scanning should be stopped If i get an appropriate response from the server. Service is called **DataTransferService**, gps scanner is called **GPSTracker** for this and service . The problem is that I  can't get a proper Context for my GPSTracker in my new Thread(new Runnable()). 
If i create a ThreadHandler my MainActivity will freeze. In addition, context is also null even if I'm initializing in my service to use later.

Here is my `DataTransferService.java`

```
public class DataTransferService extends Service {
final static String LOG_TAG = "---===> service";
private boolean isRunning = false;
private GPSTracker gps;
private double lat;
private double lng;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand");
    if (!isRunning) {
        StartLocationService();
        isRunning = true;
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    isRunning = false;
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy");
}

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onBind");
    return null;
}

private void StartLocationService(final String login, final String password) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "StartLocationService() started");

            while (true) {
                //CHECK IF SERVICE IS RUNNING
                if (!isRunning) {
                    stopSelf();
                    break;
                }

                //HERE IS THE PROBLEM <----------------
                gps = new GPSTracker(getApplicationContext());

                //GETTING GPS INFO
                if(gps.canGetLocation()){
                    lat = gps.getLatitude();
                    lng = gps.getLongitude();
                }else{
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }

                try {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.format("location is: %f; %f", lat, lng));
                    //i wanted to send HTTP request to the server here with the gps coordinates
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //SERVICE DELAY
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(30);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
}
```

As I wanted to stop the endless loop when user presses "Stop" button I've created bool variable which indicated if the cycle should bee countinued or stopped.

**UPDATE:**
I added some debug outputs(before my Thread() and inside It) to determine if getApplicationContext() result isreally different and I found out, that all the objects are equal.
I used `Log.d(LOG_TAG, getApplicationContext().toString());` before the Thread() and `Log.d(LOG_TAG, mApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext().toString());` inside the Thread(), where mApplication - is my singleton.
Results:

```
D/---===> service(7264): com.my.program.MyApplication@40ce3ee0
D/---===> service(7264): StartLocationService() started
D/---===> service(7264): com.my.program.MyApplication@40ce3ee0
```

Here is my GPSTracker.java if you are interested in it: http://pastebin.com/p6e3PGzD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked why your Activity will be frozen if you use `HandlerThread`? You can also create a `Handler` out of your thread, and send data via handler within your thread.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I pass ApplicationContext into the function in a new Thread()

You don't need to pass application context as you can access it from anywhere by 
  Defining android Application class in your codebase.

Just google "define application class android example"

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

MyApplication.instance.getApplicationContext();

should be what you want. (where instance will be the singleton object you will define)

Comment: I've tried to create a singleton MyApplication which externs android.Application class but It didn't help me: i used new  AppContext() and the gps Langtitdu and Lingtitude are Zero like before. In before: my gps tracker works fine if i put it anywhere but my Thread(). Can you advice me anything else?